# tokenize a string in shellscript

Tags: string, shell

how do I tokenize a string in shellscript? 
for example: given string "a:b:c" and delimiter ":", I would like to return an array {a,b,c}
it's equivalent to java's StringTokenizer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/918886/split-string-based-on-delimiter-in-bash

Comment: @Anders Lindahl: yes bash is ok

Comment: excellent link, elegant answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var="a:b:c"
OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS=":"
read -a array <<< "$(printf "%s" "$var")"
IFS=$OLDIFS
echo ${#array[@]}
echo ${array[0]}
echo ${array[1]}
echo ${array[2]}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
echo "a:b:c" | awk -F":" '{print "{"$1",",$2",",$3"}"}'
```